# How do I do this simple task in JQuery...show an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have many of these loading signs.

```
<span id="loading" rel="1n" style="display:none;">Loading...</span>
<span id="loading" rel="2a" style="display:none;">Loading...</span>
<span id="loading" rel="3w" style="display:none;">Loading...</span>
```

Notice the only difference is **rel**.

How do I write a JQuery script so that I choose which one to show?:

```
$("#loading").show() where rel = "2a"?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tries in this way:

```
$("#loading[rel='2a']").show();
```

**Edit**

Quite simply, no matter the language, is a simple concatenation of strings

```
var yourVariable = "2a";
$("#loading[rel='"+yourVariable+"']").show();
```

Comment: What if my '2a' was a variable? Not a string. How would I put a variable in there?

Comment: Use normal string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show all spans with a rel attribute that is "2a"

```
$('span[rel=2a]').show();
```

to show all spans that have a rel attribute that begins with "2a"

```
$('span[rel^=2a]').show();
```

[More info on selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors)

also, id's should be unique per element so I would recommend using classes to mark loading images instead of id.

so you would have

```
<span rel="1n" style="display:none;" class="loading-message">Loading...</span>
<span rel="2a" style="display:none;" class="loading-message">Loading...</span>
<span rel="3w" style="display:none;" class="loading-message">Loading...</span>
```

and your jquery would be:

```
$('.loading-message[rel^=2a]').show();
```

**Update:** to do a variable just do:

```
var x = "2a";
$('span[rel^='+x+']').show();
```

Comment: What if my '2a' was a variable? Not a string. How would I put a variable in there?

Comment: Yes, I agree completely IDs should be unique and he should be using CLASS instead. Some of the answers provided by people here may not even work, because he's got three elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#loading[rel=1n]').show();
```

But, you really shouldn't have repeated ID's in your dom.